# How do I Calulate the Sum of several "Money" Columns in a computed property in Lightswitch C#?

Tags: c#, lightswitch-2013

I am developing a Lightswitch Application and in one of the Entities I have several currency type properties and I would like to add them all up in one calculated property using C#. For instance:

I have 3 columns Amount1
                 Amount2
                 Amount3
And would like the total sum of the 3 fields.

With result = **Amount1 + Amount2 + Amount3**

The field will compute only if none of the fields have a null value.

Answer (score 1):

Make your field / property Required it wil automaticly initialise: 0

Note:In the latest versions of Lightswitch there is no more Money field: no more hastle

Comment: Johan, Thank you for your response. I did not realize that making the fields "required" would not actually nag the user at runtime to go and fill in the fields rather than auto-fill the fields with $0.00. Excellent.  As far as the latest version goes, I am using VS 2013 v 12.0.31101.00 Update 4 and assumed that it is the latest version.  Thank you for your help.  Mark